# im uploading the video and then error comes, could you help to fix it?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

TypeError: yii\base\View::{closure}(): Argument #2 ($model) must be of type Video, common\models\Video given
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: yii\base\View->{closure}()
#1 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid\ActionColumn.php(219): call_user_func()
#2 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid\ActionColumn.php(245): yii\grid\ActionColumn->createUrl()
#3 [internal function]: yii\grid\ActionColumn->yii\grid{closure}()
#4 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid\ActionColumn.php(250): preg_replace_callback()
#5 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid\Column.php(111): yii\grid\ActionColumn->renderDataCellContent()
#6 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid\GridView.php(525): yii\grid\Column->renderDataCell()
#7 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid\GridView.php(494): yii\grid\GridView->renderTableRow()
#8 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid\GridView.php(358): yii\grid\GridView->renderTableBody()
#9 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\BaseListView.php(160): yii\grid\GridView->renderItems()
#10 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid\GridView.php(326): yii\widgets\BaseListView->renderSection()
#11 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\BaseListView.php(135): yii\grid\GridView->renderSection()
#12 [internal function]: yii\widgets\BaseListView->yii\widgets{closure}()
#13 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\BaseListView.php(138): preg_replace_callback()
#14 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\grid\GridView.php(301): yii\widgets\BaseListView->run()
#15 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Widget.php(146): yii\grid\GridView->run()
#16 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\backend\views\video\index.php(42): yii\base\Widget::widget()
#17 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(347): require('D:\OpenServer9\...')
#18 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(257): yii\base\View->renderPhpFile()
#19 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\View.php(156): yii\base\View->renderFile()
#20 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(407): yii\base\View->render()
#21 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\backend\controllers\VideoController.php(59): yii\base\Controller->render()
#22 [internal function]: backend\controllers\VideoController->actionIndex()
#23 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array()
#24 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(178): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams()
#25 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(552): yii\base\Controller->runAction()
#26 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction()
#27 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(384): yii\web\Application->handleRequest()
#28 D:\OpenServer9\domains\teamlara.com\yii2-app-advanced\backend\web\index.php(18): yii\base\Application->run()
#29 {main}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The error looks like you've forgotten to put
`use common\models\Video;` in view template where you use that class in closure parameter.